# Swift button turning blue without reason

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button in swift that is blue and I haven't a clue why. I'm using the same code in two different viewcontrollers and one is blue for some reason.

Im still new to iOS development, so I'm wondering if anybody knows anything about this?

[image]
[image]

They are both using the same function. And There are no assets that are blue. I tried it with a different icon and it wasn't blue.

I also checked to see if any color changing was implemented on the button but it has no calls on it.

```
private func prepareSearchView() {
        searchShadowView.backgroundColor = .white

        searchShadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        searchShadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
        searchShadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        searchShadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 2
        searchShadowView.layer.masksToBounds =  false
        searchShadowView.layer.cornerRadius = 2

        view.addSubview(searchShadowView)
        view.bringSubview(toFront: searchShadowView)

        searchShadowView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            searchShadowView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            searchShadowView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            searchShadowView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            searchShadowView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: searchViewHeight)
            ])

        searchView.backgroundColor = .white
        searchView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        searchView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.segmentedControlBackgroundGray.cgColor

        view.addSubview(searchView)
        view.bringSubview(toFront: searchView)

        searchView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            searchView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            searchView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            searchView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            searchView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: searchViewHeight)
            ])

        let glassImageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "glassIcon"))
        searchView.addSubview(glassImageView)
        glassImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            glassImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchView.topAnchor, constant: 14),
            glassImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            glassImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchView.bottomAnchor, constant: -14),
            glassImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 19)
            ])

        let searchButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        searchButton.setTitle("Where do you want to eat?", for: .normal)
        searchButton.setTitleColor(.placeHolderGray, for: .normal)
        searchButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.mediumFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        searchButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        searchButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

        searchView.addSubview(searchButton)
        searchButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            searchButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchView.topAnchor),
            searchButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: glassImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 10),
            searchButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchView.heightAnchor),
            ])

        filterButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "filterIcon"), for: .normal)
        filterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(filterButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        searchView.addSubview(filterButton)
        filterButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            filterButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchView.topAnchor),
            filterButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 10),
            filterButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchView.bottomAnchor),
            filterButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            filterButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25)
            ])
    }
```

Comment: Are you referring to `filterButton`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to images acting as templates and taking on the button tint colour.
You can stop this from happening by taking a copy of the image with a different rendering mode:

```
filterButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "filterIcon").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
```

Comment: But this isn't true for `UIButton`. Images default to being used as templates for `UIBarButtonItem` and tab bar items, but not `UIButton`.

Comment: @rmaddy if the button type is `.system` then by default images will be treated as `.alwaysTemplate`

Comment: @MaxChuquimia Then the simpler solution is to create the button with `.custom` instead of `.system`.

Comment: @rmaddy Personally I tend to avoid creating `.custom` buttons (and recommend to others to always use `.system` too) because the `.system` buttons come with Apple's free touch-down animation which I think (in most cases at least) is expected by the user and provides a better/consistent experience.